# Docker image statistics from hub.docker.com

Tags: docker, dockerhub

I have a docker image on hub.docker.com.  Is there a way to find out who is using my docker image or who is pulling it?  Any statistics that hub.docker.com can provide.

Comment: Pull could be anonymous, so afraid cannot know who is pulling it.

Comment: Did you find a better answer to this by chance?  I'm researching the same thing.  Thanks for what you added @grg.

Comment: Docker hub does not seem to provide that info to us, unfortunately.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Only the statistics about number of pulls can be retrieved, at the moment. Then you can use Google Apps Script to record the number of pulls periodically and store it in a google sheet. You can find more about that here https://www.gasimof.com/blog/track_docker_image_pulls

Answer (score 14):

You can get the total pull count and star count from the API:

> ```
> https://hub.docker.com/v2/repositories/$1/$2
> ```

For example:

```
curl -s https://hub.docker.com/v2/repositories/library/ubuntu/ | jq -r ".pull_count"
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Since the Docker Hub does not have an out-of-the-box way to see the pull trend, I end up implementing a Prometheus exporter for myself and add a dashboard in my Grafana.

Below is the graph from PromQL: `docker_hub_pulls{repo="$repo"}`.

[image: Docker Pulls]

Here is the Github link to my project: [predatorray/docker-hub-prometheus-exporter](https://github.com/predatorray/docker-hub-prometheus-exporter).

Answer (score 0):

It's an old thread. Just stubling on this.

I also used an exporter (different one as the one from predatorray, which uses a Promotheus-database. Worked fine, only the lastupdated date was in unixformat and I couldn't get it working to show the regular date in a more readable format. It was written in golang.

After having modified a script to store pihole-stats in an InfluxDB I thought to modify that script to get the information from hub.docker.com in my InfluxDB. After a bit of testing I managed. Running it in a docker-container now.https://github.com/pluim003/dockerhub_influx